# My local copy of Python on Linux server has become disassociated from my local pip library. What's going on and how to I fix it?

Tags: python-2.7, server, pip

I have a local copy of Python 2.7 installed on a Linux Server.

The path is: $HOME/python

I set the path in my .bash_profile so that installation is the one I use by default. So, "which python" returns this installation.

I also have an installation of the pip library installed locally with this python installation. Until recently, I have been able to use pip to easily install other libraries to my local python and associate them there.

However, starting today (following a scheduler crash and server reboot yesterday), my local pip still exists, but "which pip" returns the shared pip.

What's going on and how to I point back to the local pip? Thanks!

Notably, I did not previously have to point to pip in my bash_profile (presumably because I already point to python and associated site-packages) so I have been hesitant to add code there to do that now. I figured I would ask first.

Again, thank you.

Comment: What are the results of `echo $PATH`? `ls -lF $HOME/python/bin/pip`? `which pip`?

Comment: The results are that  which pip returns the shared installation in /usr/bin/pip, the long list with classify returns the correct path to the local installation with the * symbol, and echo $PATH returns some items that I expect based on my bash_profile and some that I don't expect.

Comment: The items in path that are unexpected in the .bash_profile are some that I added yesterday right after the server crash when I was having some trouble running a script and it not finding a particular dependency. However, I learned later that this was due to the nodes not fully communicating with each other and I deleted those paths. Hmmm. Not sure they would affect pip, though?

Comment: `$HOME/python/bin` must be earlier in `$PATH` then `/usr/bin`.